# Getting BSOD with registry error on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, bsod

I have recently started getting a blue screen of death (BSOD) error very shortly after logging in to my Windows 7 laptop.  It is fine if I am in safe mode, but crashes every time when I log in to normal windows mode.  Based on the memory dump it is some kind of registry error.  I have copied the output from windbg below.  I don't recall installing anything recently and I haven't attached any new hardware.

Once I waited for about 8 hours between booting the laptop and logging in and it worked again until I restarted and logged in more quickly.  I am not sure how to proceed and if there is anything I can do to fix the registry problem.  Is there anything I can do?

```
REGISTRY_ERROR (51)
Something has gone badly wrong with the registry.  If a kernel debugger
is available, get a stack trace. It can also indicate that the registry got
an I/O error while trying to read one of its files, so it can be caused by
hardware problems or filesystem corruption.
It may occur due to a failure in a refresh operation, which is used only
in by the security system, and then only when resource limits are encountered.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000001, (reserved)
Arg2: fffff8a000024290, (reserved)
Arg3: 00000000017f7000, depends on where Windows bugchecked, may be pointer to hive
Arg4: 0000000000000374, depends on where Windows bugchecked, may be return code of
    HvCheckHive if the hive is corrupt.

Debugging Details:
------------------


DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VISTA_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x51

PROCESS_NAME:  services.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff800039ad688 to fffff8000367dbc0

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt! ?? ::NNGAKEGL::`string'+0x9d9a
nt!HvMarkDirty+0x176
nt!HvMarkCellDirty+0x150
nt! ?? ::NNGAKEGL::`string'+0x1174c
nt!CmpMarkKeyValuesDirty+0x182
nt!CmpFreeKeyValues+0x24
nt!CmpSyncKeyValues+0x7a
nt!CmpCopySyncTree2+0x2a8
nt!CmpCopySyncTree+0x6e
nt!CmpSaveBootControlSet+0x307
nt!NtInitializeRegistry+0xc6
nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13
nt!KiServiceLinkage
nt!NtInitializeRegistry+0x6f
nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nt! ?? ::NNGAKEGL::`string'+9d9a
fffff800`039ad688 cc              int     3

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x51_nt!_??_::NNGAKEGL::_string_+9d9a
```

Comment: Reinstall windows, the chances someone is going to look at all that and say THIS IS THE PROBLEM is like .0000001%. And i doubt it's anything you recently installed, windows just got corrupted. But good luck regardless.

Comment: Try a registry clean up program. Your Windows is corrupted any way, so it cannot become much worse.

Comment: you are assuming he can actually get into windows and do this. which i doubt he can

Comment: Thanks, guys.  I can get into windows in safe mode and I ran a program called Little Registry cleaner which did not help.  I am hoping there is some way to at least know what part of the registry is corrupted.  All I get is that stack trace with some kind of hex offset.  It would be nice if I could find out what the key is.  Also, I just wonder if there is some useful registry repair operation that I can do.